# Calculating the check digit of an ISBN-10 code

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I need to show that for any given ISBN-10 code $\sum_{i=1}^{10} ix_i$ holds

$x_{10} = \sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \equiv 0 \ \ mod \ 11$

I understand that $x_{10} \equiv -\sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \ \ mod \ 11$ and therefore holds $x_{10} = \sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i $.

But I don't get why $\sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \equiv 0 \ \ mod \ 11$ should hold. I mean if this were true we wouldn't need the check digit in the first place wouldn't we?

Do I misunderstand something or is there a mistake in the task?

Comment: "$x_{10} = \sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \equiv 0 \ \ mod \ 11$" does not make a lot of sense to me.  Perhaps you read $x_{10} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i  \bmod 11$  or possibly 
$\sum_{i=1}^{10} ix_i \equiv 0  \bmod 11$ - note the change in the superscript upper limit in the sum from $9$ to $10$

Comment: I think so too, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISBN-10 by example from wiki;

ISBN-10 of 0-306-40615-2:

$\begin{align}
 s &= (0\times 10) + (3\times 9) + (0\times 8) + (6\times 7) + (4\times 6) + (0\times 5) + (6\times 4) + (1\times 3) + (5\times 2) + (2\times 1) \\
   &=    0 + 27 +   0 +  42 +  24 +   0 + 24  +   3 + 10 + 2\\
   &= 132 = 12\times 11
\end{align}
$

if we consider the code as $x_i$'s $x_1-x_2 x_3 x_4- x_5 x_6 x_7 x_8 x_9-x_{10}$ is the indexing. So the summations and modulus as follows.

$(10x_1+9x_2+8x_3+7x_4+6x_5+5x_6+4x_7+3x_8+2x_9+x_{10})\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} i \cdot x_{10-i+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$